Trivy scan report convert from .json to .html
After gitlab runs the trivy  scan (v.49.1) and provides "gl-container-scanning-report.json"
I am trying to run Trivy convert  "trivy convert --format template --template "@contrib/html.tpl" /tmp/report.html gl-container-scanning-report.json
ERROR: "FATAL AWS and Kubernetes scanning reports are not yet supported"
Has anyone gotten past this error?
Is there another way to convert the scan report.json to .html
I am trying to run Trivy convert  "trivy convert --format template --template "@contrib/html.tpl" /tmp/report.html gl-container-scanning-report.json
I expected the the " trivy convert" command to actually work.

I get the same error. :-/    I am running the trivy convert command in my gitlab pipeline. The scan completed just find, but when running "trivy convert --format template --template "@contrib/html.tpl" /tmp/report.html gl-container-scanning-report.json. I receive the same ERROR:  "FATAL AWS and Kubernetes scanning reports are not yet supported". I am working on solutions now and will post when I find one.
